# How to rotate background in CSS?

Tags: html, css, background, geometry

I want to achieve a skewed/rotated background div with solid color.

Just like this:

[image: http://img59.imageshack.us/img59/367/szabloni.gif]

I know there is a trick with rotating your background to create chamfered corners but will it work out here? Or jQuery will do better?

Second problem I might have with this is a content layer (marked as red) overlaying the two background `div`s.

Can you help me please?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for any language mistakes.

Comment: You can do this, but you'll never get the edges to blend as well as they can using a PNG + alpha channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with pseudo elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/JDcF3/

I changed the colours to make visible

```
<div class="foo"></div>

.foo {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

.foo:after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    height:100px;
    width: 100px;
   -webkit-transform: skew(30deg, 0deg);
    background: red;
    left: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: I tuned it up a little to look more like shown on img:
`.foo {
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    padding-top:20px;
}
.in{
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    background:gray;
    padding-top:20px;
    display:block;
    z-index:1;
}
.foo:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    height:120px;
    width:100px;
   -webkit-transform:skew(-30deg,0deg);
    background:red;
    left:150px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    z-index:10;
}` and `<div class="foo"><div class="in"></div></div>`
but what about content layer? position:absolute?

Comment: for content layer just use, z-index. I updated above.
_while_ position:absolute for the z-index