# Fill gradient from left to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, linear-gradients

I have volume slider in my custom htm5 player that i am doing and i have problem, when you drag this volume slider thumb, everything behind it should be blue, but background color is coming from bottom. I tried: [How to rotate background in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077673/how-to-rotate-background-in-css)

but it disappeared completely.
I also use javaScript to find out how many steps are dragged:

```
function updateSlider(slideAmount) {
  mediaPlayer.volume = slideAmount;
  $('#volumeAmount').css('background-position', '0 '+ slideAmount*100 +'%');
}
```

and html:

```
<input class="volume-slider" id="volumeAmount" type="range" value="1" max="1" step="0.01" onchange="updateSlider(this.value)" name="center"style="position:relative; left:40%; top:19%;"/>
```

and CSS:

```
#volumeAmount{
  width: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:30%;
  margin: 0.8em 0.0em 0.0em;
}
#volumeAmount:after{
  -webkit-transform: skew(90deg, 0deg);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, whiteSmoke 50%, #90C7E0  50%);
}
```

it was new version from another question but here is what I had:

```
#volumeAmount{
  width: 60px;
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:30%;
  margin: 0.8em 0.0em 0.0em;
  -webkit-transform: skew(90deg, 0deg);
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, whiteSmoke 50%, #90C7E0 50%);
}
```

and some images:[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why does the gradient fill from bottom?**

It is filling from the bottom up because of a combination of the actual gradient and its positioning:

- The gradient is a `to bottom` gradient and so for the top half it have color as whitesmoke and the bottom half will have color as `#90C7E0`.
- On slide, the position of the gradient is being increased in the Y-axis and so it would naturally be moving up than towards either side.

The below snippet is a demo with a `div` element + animation (for simplicity) of the problematic code.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;  /* changed just for demo */
  height: 100px;  /* just for demo */
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, whitesmoke 50%, #90C7E0 50%);
  animation: fill 2s ease infinite;  /* just for demo */
}
@keyframes fill {
  to {
    background-position: 0 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

---

**How to make it fill from left to right?**

You can make it fill from the left to right by doing the following changes:

- Change the gradient from a `to bottom` gradient to a `to right` gradient as the fill should go from left to right.
- Change the `background-size` of the gradient such that it is 200% in X-axis and 100% in Y-axis.
- On slide, decrease the position of the element in the X-axis (that is, make it go to `-100% 0`).

Below is a demo of the fixed code. I've again done it with a `div` and animations but it should be easy to understand the changes and adapt it to your slider (since the slider is already working).

```css
div {
  width: 200px;  /* changed just for demo */
  height: 100px;  /* just for demo */
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke 50%, #90C7E0 50%);
  animation: fill 2s ease infinite;  /* just for demo */
}
@keyframes fill {
  to {
    background-position: -100% 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: wow, thanks for your answer i voted it up, but i Have problem. As i see javascript can't change background-position property, Could  I ask you for, which changes should I apply to JS?

Comment: @Nick: Did the JS you post in question work for you? If yes, just change the line which sets `background-position` to this - `$('#volumeAmount').css('background-position', (-1 * slideAmount * 100)+'% 0');`. It should work as expected. If it didn't can you create a fiddle with your actual code (whatever you have now) and I'll adapt my answer to fit that.

Comment: Yes, js code that I've made was working, but now it isn't, i updated my JS as you said but all i get is, when i load page slider's background is 50% blue from right side, and when i move slider it isn't working at all! there is no even error in console.

Comment: @Nick: Did you set `background-size: 200% 100%` like in the snippet? In your original code it was `100% 200%` and the situation you've described will happen with that old setting.

Comment: @Nick: This should work for you (it does for me :D) - https://jsfiddle.net/ako32mpd/5/

Comment: Thanks! :)) you helped me out!

Comment: gradient question = Harry answer :D